# Customizer options limited to specific user roles?

Tags: customization, theme-customizer

Is it possible to limit the selection of a specific customizer option to user roles?

Right now I have this custom control:

```
$wp_customize->add_control( 'checkin[theme]', array(
'label' => __('Theme', 'greet'),
// 'description' => 'Set theme',
'section' => 'checkin',
'type' => 'select',
'choices'  => array(
        'theme-1' => 'Background',
        'theme-2' => 'Stars (Live)',
        'theme-3' => 'Gradient (Live)',
    ),
) );
```

I would like to limit the `theme-2` and `theme-3` to only be available for a specific user role, and either be unavailable or greyed out/disabled for the other roles.

How do I do this with an array?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do this.

1. When registering a setting you can use the `capability`:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting(
    'display_excerpt_or_full_post',
    array(
        'capability'        => 'edit_theme_options',
        'default'           => 'excerpt',
        'sanitize_callback' => function( $value ) {
            return 'excerpt' === $value || 'full' === $value ? $value : 'excerpt';
        },
    )
);
```

2. When registering the control, you can use the `render_callback` argument to determine if the control will be shown or not:

```
$wp_customize->add_control( 'checkin[theme]', array(
    'label' => __('Theme', 'greet'),
    'section' => 'checkin',
    'type' => 'select',
    'choices'  => array(
            'theme-1' => 'Background',
            'theme-2' => 'Stars (Live)',
            'theme-3' => 'Gradient (Live)',
        ),
    ),
    'render_callback' => function() {
        return current_user_can( 'edit_posts' );
    },
);
```

Please note that these are completely different.
Using the `capability` argument in the setting will skip the control altogether and it will not be added to the customizer API.
Using the `render_callback` argument, the control will still be added in the customizer and it will be available from the API, it will just be hidden.
If hidden (but still exposed in the API) I can open the console and do this to show it - even though you've hidden it:

```
wp.customize.control( 'checkin[theme]' ).activate()
```